# Why does `solana program show <address>` and `solana accounts <address>` return different values for the `data length` and `balance` fields

Tags: solana-program, account, solana-cli

Originally asked in the [SolanaU discord](https://discord.com/channels/964525721416515634/964525723014561847/1120450735088349336).

Is there a reason why the Solana CLI will return different values for `solana program show` and `solana account`?

`solana program show 3KS2k14CmtnuVv2fvYcvdrNgC94Y11WETBpMUGgXyWZL` output is

[image]

While that of `solana account 3KS2k14CmtnuVv2fvYcvdrNgC94Y11WETBpMUGgXyWZL`

[image]

To add to this, if the difference in the balance has to do something with `rent` and the data field has something to do with `length in memory` vs `length for storage`, shouldn't the fields labels communicate this clearly?

Answer (score 5):

```
solana program show
```

shows the program and the size of the Executable Data account. This is where the actually .so file will be depoyed to and takes up the most of the cost for deploying a program.

```
solana account
```

shows you the rent that the program account itself costs.

If you open the program in https://explorer.solana.com/address/3KS2k14CmtnuVv2fvYcvdrNgC94Y11WETBpMUGgXyWZL you will see both accounts there.

You can always use

```
solana rent <amountOfBytes>
```

to figure out how much rent and account will cost.

```
solana rent 5216
```

will return 0.03719424 SOL for the executable data for example.

[image]

[image]